# Find a set of representatives up to conjugation for the group $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z} / p)$ of $2 \times 2$ invertible matrices.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be a prime number at least 3. Find a set of representatives up to conjugation for the group $\mathrm{GL}(2, \mathbb{Z} / p)$ of $2 \times 2$ invertible matrices.

This is my attempt at a solution:

Consider the following cases

1. $M = \begin{pmatrix}
       a & 0 \\ 0 & b
   \end{pmatrix}$. This matrix belongs in the center of our group and thus each distinct element forms its own conjugacy class.
2. $M = \begin{pmatrix}
       a & 0 \\
       c & b
   \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
       a & c \\
       0 & b
   \end{pmatrix}$. Conjugacy preserves eigenvalues, and so matrices with different eigenvalues must be in different conjugacy classes.

3. matrices that don't have eigenvalues in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Not sure how to deal with this case at all.

Comment: A general approach is via [rational canonical forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form), but I'm guessing you don't know about those yet. In case 1, are you sure that these matrices are all in the centre of the group? Do you know anything about finite fields and extensions of finite fields?